# Java format modifiers doubles in string

Tags: java, printf, formatting

I received an assignment at university in Java where I have to use `printf` to format output to the console. It was all nice and dandy but for some reason I am getting the output `10500.000000000002`, the right output should be `10500.00`. I tried to use the `%0.2f`, but because I formatted in a `String` I cannot do it.

This is the line in question:

```
System.out.printf("\nAge Depreciation Amount:%66s","$"+ ageDepreciationAmount);
```

Can you please suggest a way to format this properly? Please keep in mind this is an introductory course to java, which means I am a complete disaster when it comes to programming.

Comment: *I am a complete disaster when it comes to programming* xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%0.2f` is not correct. You should use `%.2f`:

Example:

```
System.out.printf("Age Depreciation Amount: %.2f\n", ageDepreciationAmount);
```

Or if `ageDepreciationAmount` is a `String` do

```
System.out.printf("Age Depreciation Amount: %.2f\n", Double.parseDouble(ageDepreciationAmount));
```

BTW we usually add the `\n` after the printf, and not before.

Output:

```
Age Depreciation Amount: 10500.00
```

If you want to fill the output with spaces, you would use `%66.2`, where `66` is the total width, and `2` is the number of decimal digits. However this only works for numbers. Since you need to also print the dollar sign, you can do it in two steps like this:

```
    double ageDepreciationAmount = 10500.000000000002;
    double ageDepreciationAmount2 = 100500.000000000002;

    String tmp = String.format("$%.2f", ageDepreciationAmount);
    String tmp2 = String.format("$%.2f", ageDepreciationAmount2);

    System.out.printf("Age Depreciation Amount: %20s\n", tmp);
    System.out.printf("Age Depreciation Amount: %20s\n", tmp2);
```

Output:

```
Age Depreciation Amount:            $10500.00
Age Depreciation Amount:           $100500.00
```

Comment: OK thank you that works, but now how do i move the 10500.00 to the right a certain amount of space.

In my previous example it moves the output after the age depreciation amount 66 spaces to the right then it outputs the dollar sign and the 105000.00.  So it looks like

Age Depreciation Amount______________________________$10500.00

Answer (score 2):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
String result = df.format(10500.000000000002);
```